# Python.pandas ¿Cómo indexar con un MultiIndex formado por dos keys: enteros y datetimes?

Tags: python, pandas

**Mi dataframe es de la siguiente forma**:

```
data.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

MultiIndex: 28422031 entries, (1001, Timestamp('2018-01-01 00:00:00')) to (10297, Timestamp('2019-12-31 23:45:00'))

Data columns (total 4 columns):

 '#'   Column      Dtype  
 ---  ------      -----  

 0   intensidad  float64

 1   ocupacion   float64

 2   velocidad   float64

 3   carga       float64

dtypes: float64(4)

memory usage: 1.0 GB
```

**No consigo indexar por ejemplo**:

- Año: data[pd.to_datetime('2018')] ó data[pd.to_datetime(2018)]
- id: data[1001] ó data[1001:1005]
- Ambas keys: data[(1001, pd.to_datetime('2018')] ó data[(1001, pd.to_datetime(2018)]

¿Cómo habría que realizar la indexación?

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que te refieres a insertar una columna nueva al DataFrame. En este caso es tan simple como hacer lo siguiente:

`nombre_df["nombre_nueva_columna"] = datos`

Por ejemplo aquí me creo un ejemplo y te lo voy explicando en los comentarios.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Creo un dataframe (3,3 ) de ejemplo
a = np.random.rand(3, 3) 
df_a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['longitud', "posicion", "pulgadas"])

#Introduzco una nueva columna, fecha
df_a['fecha'] = pd.date_range("1-1-2018", "1-3-2018")
print(df_a)

#Cambio la columna, para que fecha sea la primera 
df_a.columns = [df_a.columns[-1]] + df_a.columns[:-1].to_list()
```

Ahora si lo que quieres es juntar las dos columnas debes de usar `merge()`, por ejemplo, las podemos juntar por su indice:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Creo dos dataframes de ejemplo
a = np.random.rand(3, 3) 
df_a = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['longitud', "posicion", "pulgadas"])
df_b = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range("1-1-2018", "1-3-2018"), columns=['fecha'])
df_b['id_'] = range(3)

#Los junto por su posición, es decir pego una al lado de otra
print(df_b.merge(df_a, left_index=True, right_index=True))
```

Si no tienen ambos DataFrame un ID común puedes usar eso. Si tienen alguna coluna compartida puedes usar el argumento *how* para hacerlo como en SQL un `LEFT JOIN` o `INNER JOIN`, etc. Te dejo la documentación de Pandas sobre este operador, que es muy buena, para que aprendas los disintos métodos [aquí.](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)

### UPDATE

Para acceder a un valor mediante sus indices en pandas, con un DataFrame `MultiIndex` tan solo tienes que usar el método  `loc()`, igual que con un DataFrame normal. Pero debes crear una *tupla*, separada por comas. Te dejo el ejemplo:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#Creo un multiindice
arrays = [np.array(['bar', 'bar', 'baz', 'baz', 'foo', 'foo', 'qux', 'qux']), np.array(['one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two', 'one', 'two'])]

#Creo el DataFrame Multiindice (Jerárquico) de ejemplo
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(8, 4), index=arrays)

#Accedemos a los datos que tienen indice, bar y two.
df.loc[("bar", "two")]
```

[Aquí te dejo la documentación de Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), por si quieres saber más sobre DataFrames Jerarquicos

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta. Pero mi consulta iba relacionada simplemente con como indexar (seleccionar) datos en un MultiIndex de dos claves filtrando por una de ambas claves o por las dos simultaneamente. He mirado la documentación y parece sencillo, pero cuando lo intento con los casos simples que indiqué en la pregunta, me devuelve error...

Comment: Perdona con lo de indexar pensé que te referías a juntar los dos DataFrames. Te he hecho un update de la pregunta, confírmame que es lo que realmente estás preguntado!

Comment: De nuevo, gracias por tu respuesta. Ese ejemplo lo conozco, pero me ocurre lo siguiente. Como indicaba en la consulta inicial, el MultiIndex está formado por dos claves ('id': int64 y 'fecha':Timestamp), si yo formo la tupla (10297, pd.to_datetime(''2019-12-31 23:45:00')) que pertenece al MultiIndex me indica "KeyError". Y no sé entonces cómo debo hacerlo...

Comment: Da igual que el campo sea fecha, al final para Pandas es un String a seleccionar es exactamente lo mismo. En el caso de que no te funcione, edita tu pregunta, añadiendo más información, es decir el código con el que estás intentando indexar y el ejemplo que esperarías obtener por favor